# ireport iterating through data Collection and accesing fields

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I want to create simple report with jasper iReport.
I don't know how to iterate thought object C fields. For that purpose I created sub report.
Example of my classes:

```
public class D {
    private A a;
    private B b;
    private ArrayList<C> c;
    //getters setters
}

public class C {
   int id;    
   String name;
   // getters setters
}
```

In main report I declared :

```
<subreport>
.....
<dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource($F{c})]]></dataSourceExpression>
<subreportExpression><![CDATA["C:\\path\\report1_subreport2.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
</subreport>
```

In sub report :

```
<field name="c" class="java.util.Collections"/>
```

**My question: how to access fields of class C?**

I tried to change class `java.util.Collections` to C, to create fields with names of C but nothing helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you define the fields, do it as follows

`<field name="c.id" class="java.lang.String"/>`

`<field name="c.name" class="java.lang.String"/>`

where c is the object and, id and name are the fields of class C. 
Also make changes in the class as in the code.

Comment: This is was solution. Thank you for help.